# jQuery - How to select one particular field in a particular table row?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I would like to **select the field @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.FromUserID) in a particular row in my table.**

I **know I can select a row in my table by writing: var tableRow = $("#row-" + contactInfoRequestId);**

**But how do I manage to select the field FromUserID and get to its content?**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr id="row-@item.ContactInfoRequestID">
    <td>

            </td>

    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.FromUserID)
            </td>

    <td>

            </td>
</tr>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a Class:

```
<td class="fromuserid">
    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.FromUserID)
</td>
```

and select accordingly:

```
var content = $("#row-" + contactInfoRequestId+" .fromuserid").html();
```

Comment: Thank you all, I found it most easy to use Christophs method as I actually have multiple fields in the TD:               @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.FromUserID, new { @class = "fromuserid" })
var content = $("#row-" + contactInfoRequestId + " .fromuserid").val();

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [`:nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) is perfect for this if you want to select the 2nd `td` but don't want to add classes or IDs to your HTML:

```
 var secondTableCell = $("#row-" + contactInfoRequestId + " td:nth-child(2)");
```

This would select the 2nd td in the row you've specified.

To get it's content, just use jQuery's [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HTML 5, you could use data-attributes instead of hidden inputs.

```
<td data-fromUserID="@item.FromUserID">

In jquery: 

var fromUserID = $("td").attr("data-fromUserID");
```